# Qemu socket communication

Tags: linux, sockets, qemu

I am trying to do a simple communication between a server (running on Ubuntu from Qemu with Cortex-A53 cpu) and a client (running on CentOS from my pc), using sockets.

If I run the C++ code only from Centos (both client.c and server.c) it works fine. Same if I run both from Ubuntu. But if I start the server.c from Ubuntu and client.c from CentOS the communication doesn't work.

The C code I'm using is from this tutorial:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/

The Qemu command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2048 -smp 2 -cpu cortex-a53 -M virt -nographic   \
        -pflash flash0.img   \
        -pflash flash1.img   \
        -drive if=none,file=${IMAGE},format=qcow2,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0   \
        -drive if=none,id=cloud,file=cloud.img,format=qcow2 \
        -device virtio-blk-device,drive=cloud   \
        -device virtio-net-device,netdev=user0 \
        -netdev user,id=user0,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22  \
        -device virtio-serial \
        -chardev socket,id=foo,host=localhost,port=8080,server,nowait \
        -device virtserialport,chardev=foo,name=test0
```

When I run server.c from Qemu and client.c from my pc. I see that the server.c it's blocked at `accept()` function and client.c it's blocked at `read()` function.

If I run the following command on Ubuntu:
`$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` I get this:

```
systemd-r   644 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  15994      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd        745            root    3u  IPv4  18696      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        745            root    4u  IPv6  18699      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
server    14164            root    3u  IPv4  74481      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

If I run the same command on CentOS I get this:

```
qemu-syst 57073 ibestea   10u  IPv4 2648807035      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
qemu-syst 57073 ibestea   13u  IPv4 2648807037      0t0  TCP *:10022 (LISTEN)
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to connect to the socket from server part by using host address and port, but to access the Qemu data I had to connect to the socket using file descriptor /dev/vport3p1.

The server.c file should look something similar to this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define DEV_PATH "/dev/vport3p1"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    int     dev_fd;

    printf("SERVER: get an internet domain socket\n");
    if ((dev_fd = open(DEV_PATH, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
                exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("SERVER: opened file descriptor first time  = %d\n", dev_fd);
    }

    valread = read( dev_fd , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );
    valread = write(dev_fd , hello , strlen(hello));
    printf("Hello message sent\n");
    return 0;
}
```